# Facebook Javascript Login Example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to make a ASP MVC 3 website with Facebook auth system. 
I want to add users to my database when they connect to the website so that I can save their posts on the web site. The problem is that I couldn't manage to do a proper login/logout system. I have tried the C# sdk and the Javascript SDK. I have also read some sample code that I found out at web but it's no use...
Can anyone provide me a mvc 3 / javascript login/logout system? 
 Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you gotten the facebook javascript API setup? What happens when you call FB.login?

Comment: I've managed to run the JDK. <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button> makes login button show up. When clicked everything seems to work fine. Just one problem. How do I make the logout button show up if user is not connected???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried sample "CSMvc3FacebookApp" from Facebook C# SDK ( http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ )?

Comment: It is working in sense that I can reach users name, surname, etc once user is connected to the facebook. Yet my problem is more like should I do the connections with JDK or C#? And how do I add some of the users data to my own database so that I have some kind of a relationship between my db and facebook.

Comment: Once user is connected to the facebook, you can get his facebook ID and add corresponded record to your database. You need some server code to do this.